# How do you compare two int arrays elements separately in Java and see which is the greater element?

Tags: java

So I have to make a game that compares two int arrays elements separately and see if one is greater than the other or if they equal and print a message declaring which player won or if it was a draw. Both players are given 7 cards so they have to be compared 7 times each in a different round.
I'm stuck when it comes to comparing each number I cant get seem to get it to work and I don't really know how to make it so every iteration declares a new round would that have to be done separately 7 times?
This is what I currently have after many attempts.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Exercise1 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[] playerOne = new int[6];
    int[] playerTwo = new int [6];
    
    
    
    playerOne[0] = 10;
    playerOne[1] = 6;
    playerOne[2] = 8;
    playerOne[3] = 9;
    playerOne[4] = 7;
    playerOne[5] = 12;
    playerOne[6] = 7;
    
    playerTwo[0] = 7;
    playerTwo[1] = 6;
    playerTwo[2] = 9;
    playerTwo[3] = 5;
    playerTwo[4] = 2;
    playerTwo[5] = 8;
    playerTwo[6] = 11;
            
    
     for (int i = 0; i <= playerOne.length - 1; i++) {
         if (playerOne[i] < playerTwo) {
             
         }
```

Comment: How do you define 'greater'? Each element is greater? The majority of elements (by count) are greater? The total of all elements is greater? I'm just a little unclear on when this message should be printed and what determines a winner/loser. But if you just need to be able to loop through both arrays, you can do similar to what you have ```for (int i = 0; i < playerOne.length; i++) { for ( int j = 0; j < playerTwo.length; j++ ) { if ( playerOne[i] < playerTwo[j] ) { ...```

Comment: So say for example round 1 would be 10 vs 7 so 10 would be the greater number so would that code you put still stand? The message would print at the end of each round so every iteration would print the result of their comparison.

Comment: So, each major round is 7 cards to each player and each minor round is the comparison of two cards? Then it should print a winner with each minor round and an overall winner after the major round? And you want it to start a new major round if any major round ends in a draw?

Comment: Yes thats all right apart from a new major round starting that isn't part of the assignment it all takes place in the one major round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 variables that holds each ones score, increment the one that has the bigger card for each round, at the end find the biggest score

```
int[] playerOne = {10, 6, 8, 9, 7, 12, 7};
int[] playerTwo = {7, 6, 9, 5, 2, 8, 12};

int scorePlayerOne = 0, scorePlayerTwo = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= playerOne.length - 1; i++) {
    if (playerOne[i] < playerTwo[i]) {
        scorePlayerTwo++;
    } else if (playerTwo[i] < playerOne[i]) {
        scorePlayerOne++;
    }
}

if (scorePlayerOne < scorePlayerTwo) {
    System.out.println("Player Two wins");
} else if (scorePlayerTwo < scorePlayerOne) {
    System.out.println("Player One wins");
} else {
    System.out.println("Draw");
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot and I was able to solve the exercise. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to compare the elements at the same indices to each other so your code is almost good:

- compare `playerOne[i]` to `playerTwo[i]` and do whatever is appropriate (e.g. count the score)
- keep in mind that the maximum index is defined by the shorter array so either make sure they both have the same length or use `i < Math.min(playerOne.length, playerTwo.length)`.

However, it might be better to rethink your approach (which might be a later exercise though): instead of maintaining 2 separate arrays of "round" scores try to put it into one by introducing a `RoundResults` class (or similar) and ideally using a list (which has dynamic length).

Example (simplified):

```
class RoundResult {
   private int playerOneScore;
   private int playerTwoScore;

   //constructor, getters and setters
}

List<RoundResult> rounds = new ArrayList<>();
rounds.add(new RoundResult(10, 7));
rounds.add(new RoundResult(6, 6));
...


 for(RoundResult round : rounds) {
   if( round.getPlayerOneScore() < round.getPlayerTwoScore() ) {
      //player 2 won that round
   } else if( round.getPlayerOneScore() > round.getPlayerTwoScore() ) {
      //player 1 won that round
   } else {
      //it was a draw
   } 
 }
```

Doing it like this has several advantages:

- using a list doesn't require to know the number of rounds at compile time (e.g. when you'd want to go on until one player has won at least 2 rounds more than the other with a minimum of x)
- you have only one list so you don't have to make sure 2 arrays or lists have the same size and order
- you could even add methods to `RoundResult` like `boolean isDraw() { ... }`

Comment: That last bullet point here is the key. Arguably, the whole point of OOP is data and method encapsulation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply this advice really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] playerOne = {10, 6, 8, 9, 7, 12, 7};
int[] playerTwo = {7, 6, 9, 5, 2, 8, 12};

int position = 0;

for(int i = 0; i< playerOne.length; i++)
    position += Integer.compare(playerOne[i], playerTwo[i]);

String result = (position < 0)? "Player One": (position > 0)? "Player Two" : "Equal";
System.out.println(result);
```

The For loop iterates through one element per array per iteration, and it increments or decrements the 'position' variable by comparing the elements in an iteration.

If Player One is greater then the final value of 'position' would be negative as there were more decrements and vice versa.

Comment: It would be nice to add some explanatory text for those that don't understand your code. Also think of what would be the result of this: the only comparison that would matter with your code would be 7 vs 12 (the last elements) since `position` is overwritten. Thus the result would be `Player Two` when player one would actually have won more (4:2 or 5:3 if you count the draw).

Comment: Sorry, the position was not supposed to be overwritten, rather incremented or decremented based on the comparison result at each stage.